# SQL Server Stored Procedure not executing only on one machine

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

We are running SQL Server 2012, and all the developers can execute a specific stored procedure (which is overly complex), and takes a varying amount of time depending on the machine.  (Anywhere up to 20 seconds).

We right now are hosting the SQL Server instances locally, and are passing around one backup of the database to work from (we don't want a shared singular instance for dev work)

On a particular machine, it will not finish executing at all. They are all identical machines, and the settings appear to be the same.

Has anyone experienced this before?  What are some things that we can try on this specific SQL Server instance to get it working?

We tried restarting the machine, services, `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`, `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`, inspecting table locks, with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to load the database again from the backup file in the specific machine? If any case it's due to local modification in the specific system

Comment: You should add some info about the T-SQL code for the relevant stored procedure. As-is, this question isn't likely to elicit answers that would be helpful to anyone else.

Comment: It's a mess, as in over a 1000 lines of code.. The problem is where the data is coming from, which is outside of our control. A ton of joins and cursors.. I suppose I'm asking for more general methods to clear / reset SQL Server.  We have tried loading the database again @Satyajit with no luck.

Comment: It doesn't get any more clear than restoring a new copy of the database. You need to do some digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we found that finally fixed the problem was to rebuild all the indexes. They had become fragmented and so slow that the Stored Procedures were timing out.